# nopcommerce passing a dynamic "message" to displayBarNotification(message, messagetype, timeout) [_ProductBox.cshtml]

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller, nopcommerce

In the case I call the ajax method `displayBarNotification('whatever', 'success', 3500 )` in this way "whatever" gets properly displayed to the screen. However the following call fails: `displayBarNotification(@Model.Field, 'success', 3500 )` , where @Model.Field is of type string.

Would appreciate explaining this js newbie why is that and how to get around the issue.

Comment: Noticed that the called function reads the type of @Model.Field instead of the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. The field was actually not getting filled properly so it would come empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<script asp-location="Footer">
        displayBarNotification("'@Model.ShortDescription'",'success', 3500);
 </script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to call the function from the onclick of a button though

Comment: That didn't work anyway. It behaves as if I passed an empty string